# why page file size bigger than recommended?

Tags: windows, pagefile

Is it normal that my page file is really big compare to recommended? Should I change some settings?

[image: page file size]

Comment: The recommended page file size is pretty nonsensical. The amount of swap file needed depends, not on the amount of memory installed, but on the total memory needed to run all the programs you need active at any point in time, so the less memory you have, the more swap you need. So yes, I would manually set a page file of around 12GB, based on your figures. Your small initial page file will have been increased piecemeal, so it is liable to be quite fragmented, with a severe impact on performance.

Comment: Recommendation size is based on a percentage of your physical memory your actual usage is based on your systems actual need.  If you were to make it smaller you would get low/out of virtual memory errors